# cannot find the mistake with this insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I have been sitting here for 30mins and I cannot find why this is not working.

Its a simple insert query for a mysql database table but it doesn't add the data, no error appears so I have no idea why it isn't working, may be my lack of experience but I have scanned through this code and cannot find any mistake. If it is something simple then I do apologise for wasting your time.

```
if($_POST['action'])
{
$key=$_POST['Key'];
$serial=$_POST['Serial'];
$version=$_POST['Version'];

$query="INSERT INTO List (ID, Key, Serial, Version) VALUES (NULL, '$key', '$serial', '$version')";
$rez=mysql_query($query);

header("Location: index.php");

}

?>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
form {  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono}
body {  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif}
-->
</style>


<center>
<form action="" method="POST">
<h1> Add Key </h1>
<br>
Key:<br><input type="text" name="Key">
<br/>
Serial #:<br><input type="text" name="Serial"><br/>
<br/>
Version:<br> <select name ="Version">
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Add Key">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<a href="index.php">Back</a>
</center>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be using mysqli

Comment: ...nor a reserved keyword.

Comment: i read about the persons post who asked this before. Il change the field name and give it a shot. @Fred-ii-

Comment: either rename it to another word (not plural), or use ticks around it `\``

Comment: `mysql_error()` on the query would have told you about `near.......... 'key` ;-)

Comment: i removed the error 0 and it didnt give me any errors but you were correct sir i renamed the field and changed the name in the code and its working perfectly. Thank you very much,Would you like to send it as an answer and il make it correct sir?

Comment: How come your previous question was using `mysqli_` and in this code you have reverted back to `mysql_` [HUH makes no sense](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)

Comment: @RedZ great and you're welcome. The question was already closed as a duplicate ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i thought i made a mistake somewhere so i used a backup file i had before i changed it to mysqli, i fixed it now and its back to mysqli